# What are good automated testing resources?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, manual-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework

As a Beginner, i am performing Manual Testing very well.

But when it comes to automated testing, I have struggled somewhat. I have used Load Runner fairly well. i am trying to learn more about using Selenium which seems very popular.

how to be excellent in automated testing?

I tried selenium, but have had some difficulties in checking conditions.

How can i improve my abilities as an automation tester?
Is there an easier tools or approach I could use?

Comment: There are easy tools, but there are no perfect tools.  Perhaps you should learn how to program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this and from your other question about using Excel as input for Selenium, I have a feeling that you need to improve your general programming skills. If you are competent programmer, selenium is just yet another library you have to use to make your program to do what you want it to do. Not trivial, but not rocket science either (for a competent programmer).

So **do not try to find a shortcut to QA, there isn't any**. QA programming is just like any other programming.

Python is widely considered as easy language to start for beginners, so maybe try that, if you started with Java or something else (Python will be easier to comprehend). There are many free online Python courses.

Make Google search your friend, you will use it extensively.

And yes, some people find that programming does not fit their brain, and they cannot make living by programming. And that is fine too. Some of the best manual testers I know cannot program at all, and are perfectly happy and productive. For them, knowing enough about programming to be able to talk to programmers is sufficient.

To be good in test automation, you need to be competent programmer.

Comment: This is good advice, Paarthiban can learn a language (Python, Ruby, Java), then use the Selenium bindings for that language.  I have found that basic language skills are good enough in many cases - taking existing test cases and modifying them.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't always a perfect option, but I think Selenium is a good tool to get familiar with.

There is the IDE which records your steps, but getting used to writing the actual Ruby code for instance will take you further in the long run.

I'd even look into Cucumber+Selenium and it sort of sets up the path for acceptance automated testing using BDD.

Comment: Does Selenium IDE provide option, to check the conditions for comparing Actual Result and Expected Result?